# Работа со столбцами в Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть большая таблица с продажами сети магазинов, содержащая столбец с датами.

Нужно узнать за какой период у меня информация. Сделать это обычным циклом не сложно, но я пытаюсь найти способ сделать это через Pandas.
То есть мне надо взять первую дату, последнюю и в формате  datetime64[ns] сравнить разницу между ними.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Я имею данный DataFrame, он намного больше, тут только head, соответственно мне нужно получить какой период времени у меня представлен в таблице:

[image]

Данный способ выводит: `987 days 00:00:00`, а я хотел получить промежуток, что то вроде: `2010-02-05 -- 2012-02.05`.

```
df['Date'].iloc[-1] - df['Date'].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: что значит `"я хотел получить промежуток"`? вы хотите получить строку `"2010-02-05 -- 2012-02-05"` в итоге?

Comment: Извините, но из-за приведения данных в виде картинки вместо текста, вынужден  отказаться от голосования плюсом за ваш вопорос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
dt_col = "<наименование столбец с датами>"

res = df[dt_col].iloc[-1] - df[dt_col].iloc[0]
```

---

**UPDATE:** для измененного вопроса:

```
res = f"{df['Date'].min()} -- {df['Date'].max()}"
```

Comment: Способ сработал, но в конце выводит время вида 00:00:00, как это убрать?

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev, приведите в вопросе пример входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе (и в том формате, в котором вы хотите это получить)

Comment: Подправил вопрос, надеюсь сейчас стало понятнее

Comment: Да, это именно то, что мне нужно было, спасибо!